# SQL ASP.NET [Sql Command error]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FlowClientHardQ 0, 10, 1, 1, 364, Null", conn);
```

works with no error

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FlowClientHardQ @ID_User, @ID_ListGroupParIzm, 1, 1, @CIzmer, Null", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_User", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_ListGroupParIzm", ID_ListGroupParIzm);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIzmer", izmer);
```

**Incorrect syntax near the construction "FlowClientHardQ"**

Comment: what is user. Is it an id of the user or a user object.

Comment: its id , but problem is solved , except I have no idea how to send NULL value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do this:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FlowClientHardQ", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_User", user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_ListGroupParIzm", ID_ListGroupParIzm);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIzmer", izmer);
```

If you're calling a stored procedure, just set the command text to be the stored procedure name, and add the parameters like you're doing.  Set the command type to StoredProcedure before you execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Need to set [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype.aspx) to be [StoredProcedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx)?

Comment: StoredProcedure, you helped me to wrote it ^_^